# Migrating from Google App Engine to Heroku

Tags: python, google-app-engine, heroku, google-cloud-datastore

I am in the process of migrating my python application from Google App Engine to Heroku. I have managed to get webapp2 (google app engine's default request handler) working.

What I am experiencing an issue with, is the database. In GAE, I was using the built in Datastore, and my application contains all the database syntax according to that. But after migrating to Heroku, I have a lot of database choices as "addons".

I wanted to know, as to which database I should choose in Heroku, **which resembles the Google App engine's datastore the most**, so that I have to **change the least amount of code in my Application.**

Just as a reference, here's the link showing the vast amount of options available on Heroku for database choices: [Heroku Database Addons.](https://addons.heroku.com/)

Comment: SQLAlchemy should do.

Answer (score 0):

Something like Cassandra: https://addons.heroku.com/cassandraio would be closest in performance to the GAE datastore given it's column-structured nature.

However, depending on your usage patterns and how close you stuck to the Django-like API, any of the standard datastores (Postgres, ClearDB MySQL) would be about the same amount of effort to switch over to from a code perspective.